# How to switch to another module in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Just implemented a login page.

After user click the login button. 
How to navigate to my home page module?

The code should look like this:

**login module:**

```
class MyClient extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
    login() {
        //How to switch to home view here?
    }
}

module.exports = MyClient;
```

**Home module:**

```
class Home extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                 <Text>This is home page</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
module.experts = Home;
```

**I don't want to use navigator** this component cuz' I think home module & login module should not be sort of parent&child relationship.

Is there a way to switch between these two page?

Comment: You have to use the navigator. You could try to use "replace" instead of "push". With this you can achieve an instant navigation between Components.
`this.props.navigator.replace({
   title: 'Home',
   component: Home,
 });`

Comment: @nicopasso Just try to add NavigatorIOS to my app, is there a way to hide the navigation bar?

Comment: @nicopasso <code>navigationBarHidden</code> is working for me. Thx for you help. : )

Comment: Yes. There is the "navigationBarHidden" property of NavigatorIOS component.
`<NavigatorIOS
        navigationBarHidden = 'true' />`

Comment: @nicopasso that's cool : )

Comment: I'm adding my first comment as answer

Comment: @nicopasso Cool, I will upvote&accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the navigator. You could try to use "replace" instead of "push". With this you can achieve an instant navigation between Components.

```
this.props.navigator.replace({ 
    title: 'Home', component: Home 
});
```

And just in case you want to hide the navigation bar there is the "navigationBarHidden" property of NavigatorIOS component.

```
  <NavigatorIOS navigationBarHidden = 'true' />
```

Comment: I want know how I show the navigator again in the child view?

Comment: @Asaka I think you can try [this module](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router)